# Issue with generic constraint and assignability

Tags: typescript

I'd like to understand the reason why the following fails to type-check:

```
export interface Node<T extends string> {
    _type: T
}

export const makeNode = <TType extends string, TNode extends Node<TType>> (type: TType) => 
    (payload: Omit<TNode, "_type">): TNode => ({
        _type: type, 
        ...payload
    })
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
Type '{ _type: TType; } & Pick<TNode, Exclude<keyof TNode, "_type">>' is not assignable to type 'TNode'.
'{ _type: TType; } & Pick<TNode, Exclude<keyof TNode, "_type">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TNode', but 'TNode' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Node<TType>'.ts(2322)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAAjIUwDwBwewE4BcQEsB2SIIGYEMBjCEAOTgBMIAeAFUii3XIGcRmkEMBzAPhAG9Q4YQH0kATxgQAXCBpCwAX2AL68ZCAJx07EAFs8AawhlKIALwhaNScWiMWbDtwA0c03YYQmrD9ds8fAAUElKyNDZSAJQWfKrCQTB44gA2cHjksgDyeqhItB5uAERitkU8UeEesSBBgsIN4KVhIKEQbvGNIAB0vUmp6eSdSlEqQA)

I am unable to fathom what could be a potential instantiation of `TNode` in which case `{_type: type, ...payload }` would not be same as `TNode` given that payload's type is being derived from `TNode` itself and compatibility of `_type` is already guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not obvious to me at the time of writing that code (or posting the question), that `TType` was not restricted to a specific string literal, but could simply be `string` itself (or a union of multiple string literal types etc.).

So the following is a sample instantiation for which my (original) assumption didn't hold true:

```
makeNode<string, Node<"foo">>("bar")
```